# xml response to ruby hash

Tags: ruby, xml, hash

BACKGROUND

I have a XML response from a device REST API I need to pick out a particular key/value pair.  Currently I am use HTTParty get to retrieve the XML and picking out the text.  I think I am doing it the hard way and there must be a much easier method.

QUESTIONS

Is there an easier way to accomplish this to make it easier to understand and make more reusable?

XML looks like this.  I am trying to pick out the formatted="Off" key/value pair.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><properties><property id="ST" value="0" formatted="Off" uom="on/off"/></properties>
```

Code I am currently using:

```
require 'httparty'

  class Rest
    include HTTParty
    format :xml
      end

  listen_for (/status (.*)/i) do |input|
    command_status input.downcase.strip
    request_completed
  end

  def command_status(input)
  inputst = @inputSt[input]
  unless inputst.nil?
      status = status_input(inputst)
      say "#{input} is #{status}" 
  else
      say "I'm sorry, but I am not programmed to check #{input} status." 
  end
 end    

 def status_input(input)
    # Battery operated devices do not continuously reports status, thus will be blank until first change after an ISY reboot or power cycle.
    resp = Rest.get(@isyIp + input, @isyAuth).inspect
    resp = resp.gsub(/^.*tted"=>"/, "")
    status = resp.gsub(/", "uom.*$/, "")
    return status.downcase.strip
  end
```

Comment: Why not use the `parsed_response`? Or at the very least, do real XML parsing instead of faking it with regex?

Comment: That's what I was hoping someone would provide an example how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to parse the XML into a HASH using `parsed_response` and understanding the resulting HASH depth.  Thanks for the tip, Dave!

```
  def status_input(input)
    # Battery operated devices do not continuously reports status, thus will be blank until first change after an ISY reboot or power cycle.
    resp = Hash[Rest.get(@isyIp + input, @isyAuth).parsed_response]
    status = resp["properties"]["property"]["formatted"]
    return status.downcase.strip
  end
```

Thanks for your help!